# Custom folder icon for windows 10 start menu is not coming

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an application for which I am trying to create a shortcut in the windows Start menu.I am creating a shortcut in a folder inside start menu.The folder should be created with my custom icon which is present in a dll.This code works in windows 7 but not in windows 10.Below is my code-

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CreateDesktopShortCut
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToExe = @"D:\Practice\folder\nipp.exe";
            string commonStartMenuPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu);
            string[] resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
            string appStartMenuPath = Path.Combine(commonStartMenuPath, "Programs", "Custom_folder");
            if (!Directory.Exists(appStartMenuPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(appStartMenuPath);
            setFolderIcon(appStartMenuPath,"my folder");
            string shortcutLocation = Path.Combine(appStartMenuPath, "Shortcut_to_Test_App" + ".lnk");
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);
            shortcut.Description = "Test App Description";
            shortcut.TargetPath = pathToExe;
            shortcut.Save(); 

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void setFolderIcon(string path, string folderToolTip)
        {
            /* Remove any existing desktop.ini */
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path + @"\desktop.ini")) System.IO.File.Delete(path + @"\desktop.ini");



            /* Write the desktop.ini */
            using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(path + @"\desktop.ini"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("[.ShellClassInfo]");
                sw.WriteLine("InfoTip=" + folderToolTip);
                sw.WriteLine("IconFile=" + @"C:\Program Files (x86)\blah\blah\abc.dll");
                sw.WriteLine("IconIndex=-101");
            }


            /* Set the desktop.ini to be hidden */
            System.IO.File.SetAttributes(path + @"\desktop.ini", System.IO.File.GetAttributes(path + @"\desktop.ini") | FileAttributes.Hidden);

            /* Set the path to system */
            System.IO.File.SetAttributes(path, System.IO.File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.System);
        }        

    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is in windows 7 it is working fine. Even in windows 10 in the location of startmenu(C:/users/appdata../StartMenu) it is getting created with custom icon.But in the start menu view the default folder icon is coming.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research on the topic and found that windows 10 Start Menu only shows default icons.However,if the folder is pinned to Start-Menu tiles the custom icon appears properly.